# How to do a join of a lateral with a table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Can we do a join on lateral view.

I have a table which contains a column whose type is array> not I want to join col1 of each record with another table's col1

So how can i do that

Comment: I want to do a join on the value which is present in the struct inside array

Comment: When you post questions with little to zero information about your problem (examples, code you are using, desired output), you are going to get 3 word answers like mine.

Comment: ha ha ha okay sorry will update information and thanks